# SetTimeOut problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a problem with a project i'm working on.
I'm not in any way a JS expert so i'm sorry if this is a stupid thing to ask.

I have 2 video's that are on top of each other. when i call the function "switch" it plays a "static" fade effect and then switches the visability of both of the videos.

it all works fine, but when i click the button to call the function very fast, the "static" effect gliches out and everything starts to bug out.

here is the code that i am using. it switches the class name to hide the video.

```
function Switch(){
    if(videoNieuw.className == "show"){
        playNoise(1280, 720);
        btnswitch.className="controls now";
        setTimeout(function(){
            videoNieuw.className="hide";
            videoOud.className = "show";
        }, 500);

    }else if(videoOud.className = "show"){
        playNoise(1280, 720);
        btnswitch.className="controls then";
        setTimeout(function(){
            videoOud.className = "hide";
            videoNieuw.className="show";
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

The setTimeout is so the "static" fade has the time to fade a little bit and make things look smoother.

is there an alternative way so i can put this up without glitching?

Comment: Learn about `clearTimeout`.

Comment: possible typo `}else if(videoOud.className = "show"){` - should be `==`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand - lock switch when its doing and after finish unlock:

```
var lock = 0;
function Switch() {
    if(lock == 0) {
            lock = 1;
            if(videoNieuw.className == "show"){
                playNoise(1280, 720);
            btnswitch.className="controls now";
                setTimeout(function(){
                    videoNieuw.className="hide";
                    videoOud.className = "show";
                    lock = 0;
                    }, 500);

            }else if(videoOud.className = "show"){
                playNoise(1280, 720);
            btnswitch.className="controls then";

                setTimeout(function(){
                    videoOud.className = "hide";
                    videoNieuw.className="show";
                    lock = 0;
                    }, 500);
            }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var timeOut;

function Switch(){
    clearTimeout(timeOut); // Stop the currently running timeouts, if any
    if(videoNieuw.className == "show"){
        playNoise(1280, 720);
        btnswitch.className="controls now";
        timeOut = setTimeout(function(){ // Store a reference to the new timeout
            videoNieuw.className="hide";
            videoOud.className = "show";
        }, 500);
    }else if(videoOud.className = "show"){
        playNoise(1280, 720);
        btnswitch.className="controls then";
        timeOut = setTimeout(function(){ // Store a reference to the new timeout
            videoOud.className = "hide";
            videoNieuw.className="show";
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

This should prevent timeouts started in earlier clicks from executing.